# SQL DISTINCT based on two variables

Tags: sql, sybase

I am trying to eliminate duplicate values where both the Customer_ID AND the Rule_Number are the same.. Any idea how that could be accomplished?

Thanks

```
SELECT Violations_Temp.Temp_ID as 'ID', 
   Customers.Cust_Name as 'Homeowner', 
       Customers.Add1 as 'Unit', 
       Rules_Main.Rule_Number as 'Rule', 
        Violations_Temp.User_Name as 'Inspector', 
        DATE(Violations_Temp.Upload_TimeStamp) as 'Date', 
        Cast(Violations_Temp.Upload_TimeStamp as time) as 'Time'
        FROM Violations_Temp 
        JOIN Customers ON Customers.Customer_ID = Violations_Temp.Customer_ID 
        JOIN Rules_Main ON Rules_Main.Rules_ID = Violations_Temp.Violation_ID
```

In reply to the message by Loc - you can see from the results that (amongst others) homeowner Adam White has multiple records where the Rule is 11 - I need to set this so that only one record is returned for that combination

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [hasoftware.ws](http://hasoftware.ws/images/stackoverflow_002.jpg))</sub>

Comment: What is your query purpose?

Comment: I have edited the query to show the result

Comment: But you don't have duplicates. Every ID is different. Unless you want it from homeowner and rule, there is no way to do what you want.

Comment: I dont see any duplicates for Customer_ID,Rule_Number.Dont you mean homeowner,Rule_number?

Comment: you have to define a criteria of duplicity. For example you're right, rule 11 appears multiple times for customer adam white, but for each result there's a unique `Violations_Temp.Upload_TimeStamp`. Which one should we keep?

Comment: Mihai - Homeowner is derived from Homeowner_ID. Your answer returns the same values (as all the other items that are not aggregates have to appear in GROUP BY as well)

Comment: Some records having the same homeowner and rule BUT they have different inspector and date and time. Which one do you want to return?

Comment: Just want to remove (not worried which, but probably the latest timestamp(s) would suffice) the ones where the homeowner and rule are the same. I can pull out the duplicate homeowners without a problem, but sometimes it may be the same homeowner but a different rule....

Comment: Is Rule_ID the same with Rule_Number?

Comment: Rules_Main contains Rules_ID Int PKey, Section_ID Int, Rule_Number Varchar, Sub_Number varchar.... After adjusting your code (some commas were missing) it returned the correct records BUT the entire Customers Columns - I have marked your answer up though

Comment: Yes, it is not complete query. You need to decide what column you return. If my solution is correct, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this query work. I used table alias here:

```
SELECT C.*, T.Upload_TimeStamp, T.User_Name, X.Rule_Number
FROM Customers C,
     Violations_Temp T, 
     (SELECT
            T.Customer_ID,
            R.Rule_Number,
            MAX(T.Upload_TimeStamp) AS MAX_Upload_Timestamp 
      FROM 
        Violations_Temp T,
        Rules_Main R
      WHERE T.Violation_ID = R.Rules_ID
      GROUP BY C.Customer_ID, R.Rule_Number) X
WHERE
T.Customer_ID = C.Customer_ID
AND T.Customer_ID = X.Customer_ID
AND T.Upload_TimeStamp = X.MAX_Upload_Timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant way to do it but it works... (When the returned data is loaded in a DataTable)...

```
Dim vHash As New Hashtable()
            Dim vDuplicate As New ArrayList()

            For Each Row As DataRow In PopupDT.Rows
                Dim vSearchString As String = Row("Homeowner") & "_" & Row("Rule")
                If vHash.Contains(vSearchString) Then

                    vDuplicate.Add(Row)
                Else
                    With vHash
                        .Add(vSearchString, String.Empty)
                    End With
                End If
            Next

            For Each Row As DataRow In vDuplicate
                PopupDT.Rows.Remove(Row)
            Next
```